# Wordpress - Custom field suit plugin and switch blog

Tags: wordpress

Sorry no code to show.

I have a Wordpress multi-site and I'm using the Custom field suit plugin to create custom fields

I need to switch between the blogs to get info from the custom fields.

I can use switch_to_blog() to change blogs and get the custom field data from that blog. I then use restore_current_blog() to switch back to the current blog.

I can echo out the current blog and it's all correct showing the expected blogs.

After switching back to the current blog the custom field suite doesn't seem to work and I get a Invalid argument supplied error.

I know there isn't enough info here but has anyone experienced anything similar, is there a way to reset the query or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For all blogs, search engines and pages I use `WP_Query`. You have full controll about what are you showing to user. I use ACF - Advanced Custom Field there without any issues.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query